# Анимация появления текста Jquery

Tags: jquery

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сделать анимацию появления текста, если текст меняется с помощью Jquery:

```
$(function () {
$("#button").hover(function (e) {
    $("#text").text("text1");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По комменту 3:

```js
$("#button").hover(
function () {
if ($("#text").text() == 'TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2') {
  $("#text").text('TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2')
 } else {
    $('#text').stop().css('opacity', '0').html(function (_, text) { 
        return text = 'TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2'
    }).animate({
        opacity: 1 
    }, 2000);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Наведи</button>
<div id="text">TEXT1 TEXT1 TEXT1</div>
```

По комменту 2:

```js
$("#button").hover(
function () {
    $('#text').stop().css('opacity', '0').html(function (_, text) { 
        return text = 'TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2'
    }).animate({
        opacity: 1 
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Наведи</button>
<div id="text">TEXT1 TEXT1 TEXT1</div>
```

По комменту:

```js
$("#button").hover(
function () {
    $('#text').stop().css('opacity', '0').html(function (_, text) { 
        return text == 'TEXT1 TEXT1 TEXT1' ? 'TEXT2 TEXT2 TEXT2' : 'TEXT1 TEXT1 TEXT1'
    }).animate({
        opacity: 1 
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Наведи</button>
<div id="text">TEXT1 TEXT1 TEXT1</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $("#button").hover(function () {
        $("#text").animate({opacity: 'toggle'}, 'slow').text("text1");; 
    });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Наведи</button>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: Работает, но не так :( Получается, что при наведении текст пропадает. А мне нужно, чтобы при наведении текст1 переходил в текст2. У меня 4 иллюстрации, под ними текст. При наведении на иллюстрацию текст с помощью .text меняется.

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы после того, как убираешь курсор, текст снова не менялся на текст1, а оставался текст2?

Comment: Текст2 всё равно при убирании курсора рестартается :с А нужно, чтобы он как поменялся при наведении, таким и остался. У меня таких кнопочек 4 и под каждой кнопкой свой текст. Пока не наведу с одной кнопки на другую, текст не изменится.

Comment: Уф, работает) Спасибо большое за терпение и помощь :)

Comment: @Анна Чередниченко, пожалуйста)